# MS Paint running in task manager but not displaying on screen nor visible in task bar Win 7 32bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, task-manager, microsoft-paint

MS Paint (mspaint.exe) no longer displays on screen when I click on the shortcut in the start up menu or open the program by any other method. If I look in the task manage I will see and instance of it running, and if I "open" mspaint again, I will get another instance of it in task manager, however MS Paint is neither visible on screen nor on the taskbar.

This behavior has continued even after multiple reboots. This is reminiscent of a time when (I don't recall what program) I had an invisible running program, whose "window" coordinates (as listed in the registry) was way off screen. I found a solution describing the way to change the window coordinates for that program and manually edited them. After that the program appeared back on screen and was "normal thereafter. This was a Win XP Pro 32bit system. I have tried to determine if this is what I causing the problem, but I can't find any reference to a window location for mspaint in the registry.

If I boot up in Safemode, the program appears to behave normally. I am using multiple monitors when not in safemode, but even when on one screen mspaint is not displaying except in safemode.

a Yes I have tried rebooting
b No I've not gone back to a restore point, it was turned off
c mspaint.exe is not corrupt, I have replaced it with a copy from another machine, the behavior is still the same

Comment: In Task Manager, right click on the process and click [Switch to/Bring to Front] and see if does any magic or else run process explorer to find out if everything is right about that mspaint.exe

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> and then <kbd>M</kbd>, then use the arrow keys to bring the window back on screen.

This is assuming that Paint has actually been launched, yet for whatever reason has opened off-screen and will allow you to move the window into the screen area.

Comment: [Alt] [Space] + [M] where ? When the paint window is missing ? that will move the screen which is on top

Comment: Issue that key sequence as soon as it is launched.  I'm assuming it launches, but off-screen.  On initial launch of mspaint, that window gets focus.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably been over 10 years since something like this happened to me. First, you are not crazy, it's there.

I am answering as best I can from a recollection many years ago, so proceed with some caution. This answer is a bit high level, but should set you on the right path

You need to use regedit and find mspaint in the registry. One of the settings is the windows size and location. When my program disappeared (I am not sure if it was paint or something else), the window location was way off in "space".

Proceed with caution using regedit and messing with your registry. If you don't understand  what I mean by this, then doubly proceed with caution, make a back up of the file before proceeding. Google: "hkey for ms paint window positioning" no quotes needed, there are lots of posts answering this in detail.